# WebGL Error: Vertex buffer is not big enough for the draw call

Tags: javascript, webgl

Thank you very much.

**Objective**

Create an interactive viewer using WebGL.I've created a gemoetric shape using WebGL and gl-matrix library with a depth slider.

**Problem**

The slider renders, however, the geomoetric shape does not render. I receive an error in the console log. "Vertex buffer is not big enough for the draw call."

I have tried the following:

Compared buffer data size with the draw call.
Double checked the attribute pointer.
Chande the code to clear the color and depth buffer separately.
Made a simpler render function.
Added extensive debugging to the application.
Cleared browser cache
Tried incognito
Tried Chrome and Safari

Despite all the changes, the same issue persists.

My app.js code is below:

```
import { initShaders } from './shaders.js';

let canvas, gl, vertexBuffer, colorBuffer, program;
let modelViewMatrix, projectionMatrix;
let modelViewMatrixLoc, projectionMatrixLoc;
let radius = 4.0;
let theta = 0.0;
let phi = 0.0;
let near = 0.1;  // static values for debugging purposes
let far = 5.0;   // static values for debugging purposes
let left = -1.0;
let right = 1.0;
let bottom = -1.0;
let ytop = 1.0;
let eye, at, up;

const atVec = glMatrix.vec3.fromValues(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
const upVec = glMatrix.vec3.fromValues(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

let vertices = [
    glMatrix.vec4.fromValues(-0.5, -0.5, 0, 1.0),
    glMatrix.vec4.fromValues(0.5, -0.5, 0, 1.0),
    glMatrix.vec4.fromValues(0, 0.5, 0, 1.0)
];

let vertexColors = [
    glMatrix.vec4.fromValues(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
    glMatrix.vec4.fromValues(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0),
    glMatrix.vec4.fromValues(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
];

let numVertices = vertices.length;

function flatten(a) {
    return a.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []);
}

function checkWebGLError() {
    const error = gl.getError();
    if (error !== gl.NO_ERROR) {
        const errorName = glEnumToString(error) || `Code ${error}`; 
        console.error("WebGL error detected:", errorName);
    }
}

function glEnumToString(error) {
    return Object.keys(gl).find(key => gl[key] === error);
}

window.onload = function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");
    canvas.width = 800;  
    canvas.height = 600;  

    gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
    if (!gl) {
        alert("WebGL isn not available");
        return;
    }

    program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");
    if(!program) {
        console.error("Failed to create shader program:");
        return;
    } else {
        console.log("Shader program created successfully");
    }

    gl.useProgram(program);

    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(flatten(vertices)), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    checkWebGLError();

    let vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    checkWebGLError();

    colorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(flatten(vertexColors)), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    checkWebGLError();

    let vColor = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vColor");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vColor);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    checkWebGLError();

    modelViewMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "modelViewMatrix");
    projectionMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "projectionMatrix");

    render();
};

function render() {
    if (gl.isContextLost()) {
        console.error("WebGL context lost");
        return;
    }

    // temp  disable depth test
    gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    // modified to clear color and depth buffer separately for troubleshooting
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    checkWebGLError();
    
    gl.clear(gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    checkWebGLError();
    
    // re-enable depth test
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    //commenting this part for debugging purposes
    eye = glMatrix.vec3.fromValues(
        radius * Math.sin(theta) * Math.cos(phi),
        radius * Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(phi),
        radius * Math.cos(theta)
    );

    modelViewMatrix = glMatrix.mat4.lookAt(glMatrix.mat4.create(), eye, atVec, upVec);
    projectionMatrix = glMatrix.mat4.ortho(glMatrix.mat4.create(), left, right, bottom, ytop, near, far);

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(modelViewMatrixLoc, false, modelViewMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(projectionMatrixLoc, false, projectionMatrix);
    checkWebGLError();

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices);
    checkWebGLError();

    setTimeout(render, 1000);
}
```